# Are the mini Mandelbrots on the X-axis exact copies of the Mandelbrot set?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, fractals

Although not all of the mini Mandelbrots exact copies of the whole set (for example, look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51726/mini-mandelbrots-are-they-exact-copies)), are the mini Mandelbrots on the X-axis exact copies of the whole set?

[image: Here are some examples of them]

More specifically, if we shrink the entire Mandelbrot set and move it to the location of any of these mini Mandelbrots, will it perfectly overlap onto them?
(Obviously not in a trivial way like shrinking it almost completely and then putting it inside the cardioid of one of them...)

If so, is there any proof for this?

Thanks!

Comment: No, they are not exact copies.

Comment: @GEdgar I tried to confirm on some and you're correct, thanks!

Comment: No mini Mandelbrot within the Mandelbrot set is an exact copy of the whole Mandelbrot set, because there is only one perfect circle in the whole Mandelbrot set. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857237/perfect-circles-in-the-mandelbrot-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, they are not exact copies.

For example, here is an overlay of two parts, and clearly they don't perfectly overlap:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the journal article [*here*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-12/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3/), the period $3$ hyperbolic components are given by

$$c=-\frac{7}{4}-\frac{20}{9}
\left[
  \sinh
  \left(
    \omega (z)+\frac{2k\pi i}{3}
  \right)-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{5}}
\right]^2$$

$$\omega (z)=\frac{1}{3}{\operatorname {Arcsinh}}
\left(
  \frac{88 - 27z}{80\sqrt{5}}
\right)$$

Expanding numerically into Fourier series in $z=e^{i\theta}$ for $k=0$:

$$c=-1.754877666+0.009517759z(1-0.461468994z-0.026854399z^2+\ldots)$$

which is not a perfect cardioid.

Compare with the hyperbolic components for periods $1$ and $2$ [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063137/series-related-to-the-mandelbrot-set/2063153#2063153).